# Meaning of "Input"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this context:

Impact Listening(name of a book) makes listening an active and enjoyable experience for students. While featuring an abundance of natural listening input and a variety of creative activities, Impact Listening leads students to become successful listeners...

What does "input" mean?

Comment: "Content", possibly.  It is jargon.

Comment: From Macmillan Dictionary, **[input](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/input)**, sense 2b: "in psychology, information that your brain receives from your eyes, ears, or nerves".

Comment: How can the book 'feature' what my brain receives from my sensory organs?

Comment: I think the text means the book comes with a CD that is played to provide auditory input as part of the Impact Listening learning program. I suspect "Impact Listening" is both the book title and the name of the learning program. Thus, the  Impact Listening _program_ (not the _book_ itself) features an abundance of natural listening input...

Answer (score 1):

Educators and therapists often use "input" to mean sensations that the individual perceives with the five external senses (sight, sound, touch, smell, taste). Educational and therapeutic methods usually involve visual, auditory, and/or tactile "input". As Tim Romano commented, "input" is a jargon term in this context.

Comment: I found the quoted sentence almost unintelligible. Even with your explanation about therapeutic methods, I'm still having trouble understanding what it says. How would the book *feature ..natural listening "sensations"*?

Comment: @TimRomano, Maybe there's a CD pasted into the back cover?

Comment: Argghhh! You beat me to it! I was just about to say, "Maybe it's an audiobook."

Comment: In fact the Amazon description says "with free audio CD".

Comment: But `sensations` are in the person, not in the content. "I'm having a strange sensation".

Comment: From Longman Dictionary, "ideas, advice, money, or effort that you put into a job or activity in order to help it succeed". Can it implies ideas and advice for listening skill that are featured?